# Simulate and compare the responses of a linear and non linear system

Tags: control-system, state-space

A metalic object is held up in air under an electromagnet. The vertical displacement of the object can be described by the following differential equation $$ m\frac{d^2H}{dt^2} = mg-k\frac{I^2}{H^2} $$ Where m = Mass of the object, g = Acceleration due to gravity, k = a positive constant, H = Distance between the electromagnet and the metallic object ( output signal ), I = Electromagentic current ( Input signal ).

How do I find the equilibrium points and write the dynamics of the system in state space form?

Also how do linearlize the system and compare the responses of linear and non-linear systems in SIMULINK?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I find the equilibrium points and write the dynamics of the system in state space form?

You should first determine the [state space model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-space_representation#Nonlinear_systems). Look for all the variables that uniquely characterize the dynamics/evolution of the system, they will be the state. (Hint: look at \$H\$ and how it changes.)

Once you determine the state \$x\$ of the system and its dynamics \$ \dot{x} = f(x,u) \$, where \$u\$ are the inputs of the system. The equilibria \$x^{eq}_i\$ are were \$\dot{x} = f(x^{eq}_i,u^{eq}_i) = 0\$, and you can have many of them. But in your question (homework?) you will be able to find infinitely many equilibria (for any \$H\$ you can find at least one \$u\$ that will make that point an equilibrium).

> Also how do [I] linearize the system [?]

Once you figure out \$ \dot{x} = f(x) \$, which will be the nonlinear state-space model. For each equilibrium point you can have a linearization, and its parameters will be
$$
A_i := \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,u)\Big\vert_{x = x^{eq}_i \\ u = u^{eq}_i} \\
B_i := \frac{\partial}{\partial u} f(x,u)\Big\vert_{x = x^{eq}_i \\ u = u^{eq}_i} 
$$

And each resulting linear model will be
$$
\dot{z} = A_i z + B_i v
$$

> ... compare the responses of linear and non-linear systems in SIMULINK?

You will have to code the whole thing in SIMULINK, one simulation for the \$\dot{z} = A_i z + B_i v\$ linear model and one for the \$ \dot{x} = f(x,u) \$ nonlinear model.